# Описание классов с использование ООП

Tags: java, ооп

На сколько корректно примерное описание классов?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Animal cat = new Cat(3,"Брсик");
    Animal dog = new Dog(5,"Вульф");

    List<Animal> myAnimal = Arrays.asList(cat, dog);
    for (Animal animal : myAnimal) {
        cat.eat();
        dog.eat();
    }
}

public interface Animal {

    int getAGe();
    String getName();

    void walk();
    void eat();
    void sleep();

}

public abstract class Canidae implements   Animal {

    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    public Canidae(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAGe() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public abstract class Felidae implements Animal {


    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    public Felidae(int age, String name) {

        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAGe() {
        return age;
    }
    public  String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}

public class Dog extends  Canidae {

    public Dog(int age, String name) {
        super(age, name);
    }

    public void walk() {

    }
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Хрум");
    }

    public void sleep() {

    }
}

public class Cat extends Felidae {


    public Cat(int age, String name) {
        super(age, name);


    }

    public void walk() {

    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Ням");
    }

    public void sleep() {

    }

}
```

Comment: А почему age и name принадлежат семействам, а не Animal? Есть подозрение, что возраст - свойство любого животного, а имя - только домашнего. В общем, что надо было такой структурой описать? [картинка для привлечения внимания](http://i.imgur.com/Q0vFcHd.png)

Comment: @Lyth очень верное замечание по поводу имени !

Comment: Необходимо описать  следующие классы(dog,cat,woolf, tiger). При описание классов нужно учесть их принадлежность к семействам, и принадлежность к animal.

Comment: Мне кажется странным, что возраст "final", у вас животные не растут?)

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО структура явно перегружена. Что изменится если интерфейс `Animal` сделать абстрактным классом и общим предком `Canidae` и `Felidae`? Ответ ничего. Стало быть интерфейс `Animal` излишен.

Вообще интерфейс описывает не сущность класса, а *поведение* класса, уже с этой точки зрения интерфейс `Animal` не выдерживает критики.

Лучше бы сделать интерфейс:

```
public interface Climbable {  //лазающий
   public void climb();
}
```

Тогда кошачий класс будет иметь специальное поведение:

```
public abstract class Felidae extends Animal implements Climbable {
}
```

Answer (score -2):

По своему скромному мнению хочу отметить несколько проблем, которые я заметил:

- Если используете поля c модификатором доступа `private`, то в названии
  стоит добавить `_` **(underscore)** (может еще стоит начать использовать `свойства`)
- В Вашем интерфейсе `Animals` описаны некоторые методы (`eat()`,
  `walk()`, `sleep()`). Все вроде бы неплохо, но если к примеру у
  собаки *бессоница* ? Или же она к примеру *не может ходить*. Или из-за
  своей *бессоницы* у нее *пропал аппетит* ? Что тогда ? Если Ваши классы с
  домашними животными реализовывают этот интерфейс, то по сути, класс который реализует интерфейс, должен описывать все методы, объявленные в интерфейсе.

На Вашем месте, я бы почитал про **очень** интересный `патерн проектирования` под названием: [стратегия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Удачи !

Comment: Спасибо за совет, изучу данный материал.

Comment: @kxko С точки зрения чистого кода, твой совет прo нижнее подчеркивание - это шум в коде (noise). Не нужно советовать шуметь и пахнуть в коде. Это не хорошо. Почитай [книгу](https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) и все пройдет. :)